# jQuery ajax not passing in multidimensional array to PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array I am trying to pass in as data through a jQuery ajax call to my PHP script.

I declared lobby_state with the following code:

```
lobby_state = [];
lobby_state.users = 3;
lobby_state.user = [];
lobby_state.user[0].username = 'john';
lobby_state.user[0].age = 30;
lobby_state.user[0].sex = 'M';
lobby_state.user[1].username = 'kim';
lobby_state.user[1].age = 17;
lobby_state.user[1].sex = 'F';
lobby_state.user[2].username = 'mary';
lobby_state.user[2].age = 51;
lobby_state.user[2].sex = 'F';
```

I'm passing in a total of 2 values, a simple string, and the multidimensional array:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "app/lobby/lobby-process.php",
    data: {  
        'action': 'update',
        'state': lobby_state
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
...
```

When I execute this, it seems to completely ignore the lobby_state value, and it only passes in the 'action' value, as shown in the Chrome developer console request values below.

[image]

I tried following all the examples of passing in arrays but nothing seems to work.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Please do a console.log of the array and paste here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass it as a JSON string:

```
state: JSON.stringify(lobby_state)
```

An example on how to declare an array properly:

```
var lobby_state = [],
    john = { username: 'john', age: 30, sex: 'M' };

lobby_state.push(john);

console.log(lobby_state);
```

You could add the object to the array directly as well:

```
var lobby_state = [{ username: 'john', age: 30, sex: 'M' }];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p8x14goy/1/

Comment: Thanks filur, one step closer!  However, when I make that change, it seems to convert lobby_state into an empty json value of '[]'.

Comment: @user3130810 The problem is that `lobby_state.user[0] is undefined`. Let me update with an example on how to declare the array properly

Comment: What if I also want to add a user count like in my original post?  I think that is what's causing the issues at the moment.  I was hoping I could keep it all under the same variable, so lobby_state would contain a single integer, as well as an array.

Comment: @user3130810 You don't need a property for it. Just look at the size of the array